# How to manipulate local files with webdav

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, file-upload, webdav

Hi so I just found out that webdav protocol allows for manipulations of local files through a browser. I have it already set up in the back end. What I would like to know is how to make it work on front end. I am using javascript with jQuery.

For example how do I create a folder?

I want to avoid plug-ins, and libraries unless I have to. I want to try the lower level stuff first and if I see that I need a plug in ill get it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out a while ago. I was thinking the wrong way. It is not the client that will do anything it will be the server. So the client can make a regular http call and just change the "type" string from get or what ever to MKCOL for example. There is also not much documentation on webdav so try and look for documentation specific to your server.